# Drawing Multiple Polygons on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, xml

I have the following php code, which obtains the data from mysql and converts it into an xml file, I implemented it to my project but I can't get it to come out the way I wanted, the code is the following:

```
<?php

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());}
// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection,'demo');
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error());
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM paths WHERE 2";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
}
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
$node = $dom->createElement("subdivision");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  $node = $dom->createElement("coord");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("pid", $row['pid']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

What I get is this:

```
<subdivision>
<coord pid="5" lat="-16.49899449" lng="-68.15313367"/>
<coord pid="5" lat="-16.50014664" lng="-68.14750318"/>
<coord pid="5" lat="-16.50719105" lng="-68.14712552"/>
<coord pid="5" lat="-16.50738856" lng="-68.15478162"/>
<coord pid="7" lat="-16.79950575" lng="-68.14613862"/>
<coord pid="7" lat="-16.79897082" lng="-68.15034432"/>
<coord pid="7" lat="-16.70394970" lng="-68.15261883"/>
<coord pid="7" lat="-16.70707687" lng="-68.14914269"/>
<coord pid="7" lat="-16.70394886" lng="-68.14501762"/>
<coord pid="7" lat="-16.70263299" lng="-68.14322037"/>
<coord pid="8" lat="-16.50882147" lng="-68.15543408"/>
<coord pid="8" lat="-16.50577663" lng="-68.15627522"/>
<coord pid="8" lat="-16.50220505" lng="-68.15594906"/>
<coord pid="8" lat="-16.50589184" lng="-68.15007824"/>
<coord pid="8" lat="-16.50921648" lng="-68.15265316"/>
<coord pid="8" lat="-16.51226042" lng="-68.15372944"/>
</subdivision>
```

but what I want to obtain is as follows:

```
<subdivision pid="5">
       <coord lat="-16.49899449" lng="-68.15313367"/>
       <coord lat="-16.50014664" lng="-68.14750318"/>
       <coord lat="-16.50719105" lng="-68.14712552"/>
       <coord lat="-16.50738856" lng="-68.15478162"/>
</subdivision>
<subdivision pid="7">
       <coord lat="-16.79950575" lng="-68.14613862"/>
       <coord lat="-16.79897082" lng="-68.15034432"/>
       <coord lat="-16.70394970" lng="-68.15261883"/>
       <coord lat="-16.70707687" lng="-68.14914269"/>
       <coord lat="-16.70394886" lng="-68.14501762"/>
       <coord lat="-16.70263299" lng="-68.14322037"/>
</subdivision>
<subdivision pid="8">
       <coord lat="-16.50882147" lng="-68.15543408"/>
       <coord lat="-16.50577663" lng="-68.15627522"/>
       <coord lat="-16.50220505" lng="-68.15594906"/>
       <coord lat="-16.50589184" lng="-68.15007824"/>
       <coord lat="-16.50921648" lng="-68.15265316"/>
       <coord lat="-16.51226042" lng="-68.15372944"/>
</subdivision>
```

how can i get this?

I am a little new to this and I would like to please someone can help me, I know I have to use a loop, try but I could not

thanks!

Comment: Sorry, the right thing is

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM paths";

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly